# Could rsync wait file created and then copy it in the same time

Tags: rsync

I want to copy file from A to B use "rsync", But the file is not exist right now in A. I run the "rsync" command on B, Can i let  "rsync" to wait until the file is creating in A, and copy it in the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we start with a command running on hostB like

```
hostB$ rsync hostA:remotepath localpath
```

If hostA has a normal shell, we can make rsync wait until the file exists by tweaking the helper command it normally runs on hostA. Depending on the environment, something like this might work:

```
hostB$ rsync --rsync-path='
    while [ ! -f remotefile ]; do sleep 1; done;
    sleep 5;
    rsync' hostA:remotepath localpath
```

- the `while` loop busywaits for `remotefile` to become available
- then `sleep 5` allows a few seconds for the contents to settle
- `rsync` is the normal remote command

  - must come last
  - must not end with newline or semicolon or comment